# Terraform backend remote config with Google Cloud Buckets

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, terraform

I'm running the below command and seeing the output that `Terraform has been successfully initialized!`

```
terraform init \
  -backend=true \
  -backend-config="bucket=terraform-remote-states" \
  -backend-config="project=<<my-poject>>" \
  -backend-config="path=terraform.tfstate"
```

However, when I run the template, it creates the state file locally instead of within GCS.

Not sure what I'm missing here. Appreciate any thoughts and help.

Comment: what version? `terraform init` has different behaviors before and after v0.9.x

Comment: Answer: https://github.com/sahas-/terraform-google-compute-engine

Answer (score 1):

When you execute the listed `terraform init` command, it seems like you don't have a `backend` block that looks like the below within any of the `.tf` files in that directory.

```
terraform {  
  backend "gcs" {
    bucket  = "terraform-state"
    path    = "/terraform.tfstate"
    project = "my-project"
  }
}
```

None of those `-backend-config` arguments you're passing tell Terraform that you want the state to go into GCS.

Without an explicit `backend "gcs" {}` declaration as above, Terraform will default to storing state locally, which is the behaviour you're currently seeing.